# send CORS post variables to a different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I have a site (SiteA) that using CORS Ajax *{see example 1}*.

I pass variables from (SiteA) to (SiteB).

This works fine, (SiteB) is appended on (SiteA), I now would like to collect the `$_post` variables received on (SiteB) and `POST` them to a different page (SiteB/Page2).

I tried a simple session *{see example 2}*, however as (SiteB) is never directly assessed the session is not active so no variables stored to be used in (SiteB/Page2).

How can I send the `$_post` variables from (SiteB) to (SiteB/Page2) ?

**Example 1**

```
 $("#abi_test").click(function (event) {
        $.post(
            "SiteB",
            {
                name: "Tom",
                age: "30",
                email: "johnsmith@gmail.com",
                uniID: "3"
            },
            function (data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
            }
        );
```

**Example 2**

(SiteB)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'Root2';
$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
$_SESSION['post-data']['name'];
$_SESSION['post-data']['uniID'];
```

(SiteB/Page2)

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])) {
    echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['userName'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Your uni ID" . $_SESSION['uniID'];
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is: If you are using ajax / javascript to make a post request to site B, you are accessing site B directly and the session should work.

Comment: yes Ajax to post from A to B, problem is i wish to use the variables posted on B in a direct page in B and as B is never access directly a session will not work